# Regular spikes in server IO

Tags: linux, server, cpanel, disk-io

I have a virtual server running on CentOS Linux 6 x64 OS.
It uses SSD Accelerated RAID Storage, has 2GB RAM and is Running Drupal 7 on Apache.

I have noticed a repeating patter of spikes in the server load.  These do not correlate to Cron, backups users or any scheduled admin operations.

[image: Disk IO over 30 days]

The spikes all seem to be around 8:00 pm UTC and the majority of them seem to hit the 0.75 mark with a could of obvious highs, lows and omission.

Is there anything I should be looking for or asking my service provider about?

**UPDATE**
This appears to be cPannel updates.  Now I need to research on how to minimise this or how often it really needs done.

Comment: You are correct, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

1. Check logs around that time - maybe some service is going to log that it's starting something periodic.
2. Start a loop tomorrow just before 8pm, which will run snapshot `ps` with CPU measurement every 5 seconds. See which process is busy.
3. Check the whole filesystem for files modified around 8pm.

Comment: So far we are confident that this is happening outside drupal.